# PL/SQL block does not execute to end when using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

**What am I trying to achieve?**

- I would like to copy Oracle procedures from one user to another using PL/SQL.
- I would like to copy all procedures - including those with compilation errors.

**Where am I stuck?**

- After EXECUTE IMMEDIATE creates a procedure with compilation errors the PL/SQL block does not execute any further.
- There is no exception!

The following two blocks of code demonstrate the problem. The first block executes as expected. The second block does not execute in whole. Procedure p3 having a compilation error is not the problem. My problem is that procedure p4 is not created.

```
-- creates procedure p1 and p2
BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create or replace procedure p1 is begin null; end;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create or replace procedure p2 is begin null; end;';

  dbms_output.put_line('Done!');

END;
```

```
-- creates only procedure p3 and exits with no error
BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create or replace procedure p3 is begin null end;'; -- compilation error (missing semicolon)
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create or replace procedure p4 is begin null; end;';

  dbms_output.put_line('Done!');

END;
```

Comment: I am curious as to why you want do copy a procedure this way?  If the procedures are almost identical, cant you generalize one and pass in additional parameters?

Comment: I get a valid error back - ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at line 3
24344. 00000 -  "success with compilation error"
*Cause:    A sql/plsql compilation error occurred.
*Action:   Return OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO along with the error code

Comment: is there a reason you don't have an application schema with your plsql objects for any user you want to be able to execute them via exec privs?

Comment: This seems to be a really poor way to manage schemas. What is the underlying rationale?

Comment: @OldProgrammer The procedures differ very much. The above code was only meant to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith In reality I am doing this via db link. I am copying an extract of my production data to a development environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go into more detail on Bob's answer: if you want to ignore compile exceptions, you'll need to wrap each `execute immediate` in an anonymous block.

```
BEGIN

  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create or replace procedure p3 is begin null end;'; -- compilation error (missing semicolon)
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN null; -- ignore exceptions
  END;

  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create or replace procedure p4 is begin null; end;';
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN null; -- ignore exceptions
  END;

  dbms_output.put_line('Done!');

END;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is an exception being raised. You see, "Success with compilation error" *IS* an exception. You can catch it by defining an exception variable and initializing it using `EXCEPTION_INIT`:

```
eCompilation_error EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(eCompilation_error, -24344);
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=712d6831ff878db8ea212d6dbccf039e)